# How to extract from all entered sentences all words containing a given letter combination in C?

Tags: c

The task is: Develop a function that extracts from a sentence the first word containing a given combination of characters. Use the keyboard to enter a few sentences and letter combinations. Based on the developed function, extract from all the entered sentences all the words containing the given letter combination. Print the result of the extraction.

Here's what I already have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int i = 0, k = 0;
char sentences[20][100], search[20];
 
void Input(void);
void Find(char search[]);
 
 
int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");
    Input();
    Find(search);
    return 0;
}
 
void Input() {
 
    printf("Enter number of sentences:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    rewind(stdin);
 
    printf("Enter %d sentences:\n", k);
 
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        gets_s(sentences[i]);
 
    }
    rewind(stdin);
    printf("Enter letter combination:\n");
    gets_s(search);
}
 
void Find(char search[]) {
    int coinc = 0;
    printf("\n");
 
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (strstr(sentences[i], search)) {
            printf("%s\n", sentences[i]);
            coinc++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nCoincidence is %found.\n", (coinc > 0) ? "":"not ");
}
```

**Example:**

**Input:**

Nice weather

It`s nice to see you!

Hi there

She`s a nice girl

**Find:**
ice

**Output:**

weather

It`s to see you

She`s a girl

Comment: Instructions are unclear. Should the word match *all* of those letters? Or is it ok if it is built up from a subset of those letters?

Comment: Add sample input, expected output & your problem details.

Comment: @Cheatah yes, it should match all of those letters. I`ll put an example in my question.

Comment: `gets_s(sentences[i]);`  --> What compiler are you using that has `gets_s()`?  Does that function truly only use 1 argument or 2 like in `char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);`.  Tip: save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: regarding: `rewind(stdin);`   The I/O stream `stdin` cannot be rewound